# What is the iOS equivalent to Android Socket programming code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, nsstream

I have some socket programming code in Android (Java) and I want to implement the same thing in iOS (Objective-C).

On iOS, `NSStream`, `NSInputStream`, `NSOutputStream` are some of the classes for socket programming.

I have doubts when comparing them to some methods on Android's `SocketChannel` class.

```
socketChannel.configureBlocking
socketChannel.setSoTimeout
socketChannel.connect 
socketChannel.finishConnect
socketChannel.isConnected
```

What are the equivalent methods in iOS classes like `NSStream`, `NSInputStream`?

And also `ByteBuffer` on Android has a `position()` method. What is the equivalent method in iOS?

I know the `NSStream` constants are there, but I am confused about how they map to Android code. Could you please suggest which methods are equivalent in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't translate code line by line. Different platforms and even different frameworks use different styles of API.

Since your question doesn't say what you are trying to do, I can only recommend that you read more about how stream and socket programming works on iOS in

- the [Stream Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html), or
- the [CFNetwork Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html) (if you want to read more about lower level (Core Foundation) networking code on iOS), or
- the [Networking Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) (if you want to read more about networking code in general on iOS)