# Send/receive data via URL-string in an WiFi network

Tags: ios

I have an IOS application where many IOS-devices, much more than seven, shall send data to an iPad via a private WiFi network. I want to do this as easy as possible, without security, i.e. sending the data like this: ´http://IP_address/$DATA´ => "http://192.168.1.25/$09963 KV".
I know how to send the data this way, but I don´t know how to make the iPad receive the $DATA. 
If I have i.e. 40 senders I hope to read the data into an array and then analyse them as soon as possible...
Hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you planning to send and receive data using your app on multiple device which are on the network following are the options.

1. Bonjour API [Apple Bonjour API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/programming.html)
2. NSStream.
3. CFNetwork

You can also see similar question in stackoverflow [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404321/what-is-the-ios-equivalent-to-android-socket-programming-code)

Comment: I also want to communicate with Android devices... That´s why I hope to find a way using my described solution... Is my proposed solution possible?

Comment: Then Socket is the best way to communicate between your apps.

Comment: I can´t find any tutorial using an iPad as server... they are using a Mac or a PC...   Do you know about a tutorial using iPad as server and an iPhone as client?

Comment: I don't know hardly whether there is any web server available for iPad or iPhone. Typically it is possible for porting a web server like apache into iOS. But the iOS is not indended for such kind of heavy load things. As you know iOS only have a very limited capability of multi tasking. You cannot create a app which always run in the background  and wait for incomming connections. In iOS you have to combine a multiple technologies like background fetch and remote notification to achieve this. And Socket is a Unix technology which you can use in any platform to communicate between apps.

Comment: Yes, a server is heavy to run and that´s why I came up with my simple ´solution´. I just want to ask a question to all the devices and then I´ll wait for about 30 seconds to give them all a possibility to answer. After 30 second I´ll analyse all the incoming data. This way I don´t need multitasking.  Today I use MultipeerConnectivity and it works fine, but the limit is 7 IOS devices...    Perhaps somebody already have done it my wanted way, or in a similar way and can give me some words? I´m grateful for all response!

Comment: I´m now using a HTTP server and my app is now working fine! :-)  Thank you for your response!